# How does JavaScript recogize event object variables?

Tags: javascript, event-handling, dom-events, parameter-passing

Quick question about JavaScript event objects - how does JavaScript know when I'm trying to pass an event variable to a function?  For example, when I define an `onclick` handler like so:

```html
<button onclick='SendMessage(event)'></button>
```

Does JavaScript pass the event variable just because I named it "event"?  If so, what other variable names does it reserve for the purpose of passing event variables? (e? ev?  etc..)

If this is the case, can they be covered by naming local or global variables "event", "e", etc.. ?

Comment: It just happens to pass it in as the first parameter, it has no idea what you've called the variable. Javascript doesn't have parameter types or even check for parameters when verifying function signatures since you can't use function overloading.

Comment: @TheZ That's not correct. `event` is a keyword in this case and it won't work with anything else. Now in your function, you can name the parameter anything you want. [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/Fj2Q8/)

Comment: It's not a keyword in any case. Calling it an "implicit parameter" or something might be more appropriate?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It *must* be called `event` in an inline event. `event` is *not* a keyword and is *not* a reserved word in JavaScript; it is merely the variable name the early Netscape engineers decided upon.

The inline text supplied for the event is effectively *wrapped* <sup>1</sup> as:

```
function (event) {
   // the inline code
}
```

IE uses the `window.event` property to pass event information, but the names coincide so using `event` will fallback through the normal JavaScript variable resolution as appropriate.

Of course, if attaching a *function object* directly then the event variable, because it's just the first parameter, can be named whatever is desired. Unfortunately IE's [`window.event`](http://docstore.mik.ua/orelly/webprog/jscript/ch19_03.htm) approach must be dealt with as well, and calling the argument `event` doesn't address it.

```
elm.onclick = function (my_event_name) {
    my_event_name ||= window.event // for IE
    ...
}
```

(I would recommend avoiding inline events as much as possible and using a library that unifies/simplifies events.)

Happy coding!

---

<sup>1</sup> This behavior is covered in detail in [HTML 5: Event Handlers, Event handler content attributes](http://dev.w3.org/html5/spec/webappapis.html#events):

> [inline event, e.g onclick, text] must contain valid JavaScript code which, when parsed, would match [a function] production ..
>
> Using the script execution environment created above, create a function object .. Let the function have a single *argument called event*.