# How to get the event object when event listener is added inline

Tags: javascript, dom-events

Suppose I add the event handler inline,use the `onclick` attribute of the element like this:

```
<input type="button" value="Submit" onclick='buttonClick()' />
```

Then this is my handler:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    window.buttonClick=function(e){
        e=e||window.event;
        alert(e.type);
        return false;
    }
</script>
```

Now I want to know how to get the event object? Since the above code will throw error:

> e is undefined.

Comment: What browser and what browser version?

Comment: It does matter,I want it work cross browser.(I use firefox now)

Comment: @Daedalus Try add the parameter. http://jsfiddle.net/QxrSe/1/

Comment: @xdazz Well, it would appear we now both understand each other, so there isn't any point in continuing this.

Comment: @Daedalus Oh, I add the wrong name, `Try add the parameter` is for `@hguser` but not `@Dedalus` who is you. Sorry for that, I understood your reply now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's *not* using the `event` variable in the inline event.

In this case `buttonClick` is a function *called* from the inline event; the called function does not have magical access to the `event` variable (`window.event` is an IE feature). Furthermore, in the post, `buttonClick` was called with 0 arguments so `e` will always evaluate to undefined.

In any case, compare with the following which will work as access to [the special `event` variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11265869/how-does-javascript-recogize-event-object-variables/11265908#11265908) is done from the *inline* event itself and the event object is then passed off to the "real" event handler function:

```
<input type="button" value="Submit"
       onclick="buttonClick(window.event||event)" />

<script type="text/javascript">
    function buttonClick(e) {
        alert(e.type);
        return false;
    }
</script>
```

(I would recommend using jQuery or another library to make uniform event access easier, but that's another story ..)

---

Note that `window.event||event` is a dirty little trick:

In IE `window.event` will evaluate to the event object and be be used as the result of the expression (so that `event`) is never evaluated. In non-IE browsers, `window.event` will evaluate to undefined (unless someone is doing some *really bad things*) and thus the result will be that of the `event` variable.

Reversing this to `event||window.event` would cause a ReferenceError in browsers (i.e. IE) that do not support the W3C local `event` variable approach.

Comment: `window.event||event` should _not_ be needed in the inline call: `onclick="buttonClick(event)` should be enough; check out e.g. [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11265869/how-does-javascript-recogize-event-object-variables/11265908#11265908).

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your code does what I think it does.. you would simply do this:

```
<input type="button" value="Submit" onclick='buttonClick(window.event||event)' />
```

Comment: I didn't downvote, *but*: `this.event` is not *guaranteed* to contain anything useful - only the local `event` magical variable and/or (depending on browser) `window.event` are - I would actually expect it to be `undefined` (but I could be wrong).

Comment: @pst Thanks for the heads-up; changed.

Comment: Hmm. The redundant `window.event||event` here, too, as in the previous answer (of user[0-9]+). Are you really, positively sure it's required (for IE)? Please tell us why, if so.

(Note: I just found the same hack somewhere in my code, too. But I recently learned from [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11265869/how-does-javascript-recogize-event-object-variables/11265908#11265908) that in fact it's pointless. For a test, I deleted it now, and the stuff still works on IE8.)