# "Event" word striked through in PyCharm

Tags: javascript, html, pycharm

I'm using the `event` word in a tabbed navigation and noticed that it is struck out in PyCharm, it says:

> undefined.

To my best understanding the "event" is a reserved JS keyword, for inline functions on HTML elements are used to pass the details of whatever happened (e.g. key or mouse button pressed to the handling function).

But this is the `event` I will get for the function defined later in my code.
Is there a better practice to prevent it to be struck out?

I only found this but it doesn't say how to circumvent it.

[How does JavaScript recogize event object variables?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11265869/how-does-javascript-recogize-event-object-variables)

It looks like that

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The usual reason for a strikethrough is the keyword/element having been deprecated (even if it still works). The visual hint is a reminder from the IDE.

Regarding `event` see [“event” is deprecated, what should be used instead?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/58341832)

But the reason can also be that you have to define the word `event` for JavaScript to recognize it, see [How does JavaScript recogize event object variables?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11265869)

You can turn off some warnings selectivly in `File` `>` `Settings` `>` `Editor` `>` `Inspections`. However this may imply that you also turn off the strikethrough for other deprecated keywords.

[image]

[image]